# error when installing rmagic gem on Ubuntu 12.04 for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, ubuntu-12.04, rmagick

I am trying to get my Ruby on Rails application working and installing RMagic gem.
But I get an error that says "Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries." Altough I have ImageMagick installed with its dependences. ( http://i46.tinypic.com/2vdl1g6.png )

terminal log http://pastebin.com/vcgkbwZR

I even tried to installed RMagic from Synaptic, but I get the same error when I run "bundle" command.

Through my search, some people had problem with lib dependencies, but I believed I have them all installed.

Another solution I found is this ( [error installing RMagick from gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131179/error-installing-rmagick-from-gem) ) a little bit old and not sure if it is going to work for 12.04. BUT, I don't know where those configurations should go.

Answer (score 1):

It is working now and RMagick recognizes where ImageMagick is located after I compiled and installed the latest version of ImageMagick from the main website. I followed the instructions: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php?ImageMagick=9s6tlikqbn5eb0u0spg5o38sa4#unix

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but try running `sudo ldconfig`, then do `gem install rmagick` again in the same terminal window/tab.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work; could you pastebin the contents of /home/peacedefender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out as well? I'm thinking that your gcc/ld config is weird or something but that file should have useful information.